# mongoose aggregate documentions with 2 dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

hello im trying to make a function that returns to me how many pepole are absent each month,
the functions takes from(what month) to (what month) and a year so like from month 3 to month 6 ,
in my mongodb database each documentation is a person with absentStartDate absentEndDate and more info about the person
pepole cannot be absent for more then 25 days
I want to count how many documents are in each month, the problem is someone can be absent from march to april so absentStart month is 3 and end month is 4 and I want to count for each month he is absent so in april i will have a +1 and in march i will have a +1

this is how far I have gotten

```js
    const grade = async (req, res) => {
    const {
        from,
        to,
        year
    } = req.query


    let egedStructure = await db.findAll(assets, {
        name: "EgedStructure"
    })
    egedStructure = egedStructure[0].content /* array of all the battalions */

    egedStructure.forEach(batt => {
        const finalGrade = model.aggregate([{
                $match: {
                    $or: [{
                            $and: [{

                                    $expr: {

                                        $eq: [{
                                            $year: '$absentEndDate'
                                        }, 9999]

                                    }

                                },

                                {
                                    battalion: batt.Battalion /* battalion name */
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            $and: [

                                {
                                    $expr: {
                                        $gte: [{
                                            $month: '$absentStartDate'
                                        }, from - 1]
                                    }
                                },

                                {
                                    battalion: batt.Battalion
                                },

                                {
                                    $expr: {
                                        $lte: [{
                                            $month: '$absentEndDate'
                                        }, to - 1]
                                    }

                                }
                            ]
                        }

                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        $month: '$absentEndDate'
                    },
                    count: {
                        $sum: 1
                    }
                }
            }
        ]).then(resp => console.log(resp))
    })
}
```

in the code I tried it only counts the absentEndDate and doesnt take in consideration the absentStartDate
how do I make it so it takes in consideration the startmonth and doesnt count it twice?